# Is it required to implement In-App-Purchase or can I simply add the paid version as a new app?

Tags: xcode, app-store, in-app-purchase

I already have a free version of my app in App Store. Now I want to add a completely new paid version of the same app (with extra features).

Is it required to implement In-App-Purchase or can I simply add the paid version as a new app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the app store, you'll see both options. There are many free "lite" versions of an app, and the full versions which you need to pay for.
In-App purchases are also common, yet they need more effort to develop.

Comment: Do not forget to accept one answer (and you might upvote both ;) )

Answer (score 5):

You can create a paid version of your app with no problem. It will get approved. So it's really up to you. But using in-app purchase makes it more convenient to the user. They will be able to switch to full version of the app without losing any data (like achievements for a game, or documents created with the free app).